# cookies and sessions is automatically destroyed after 5 minuts

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, cookies

If the user is not working in my application more than 5 minuts, my cookies and session want to be detroyed automatically.

in module config

```
'session' => array(
      'cookie_lifetime' => 60, 
      'gc_maxlifetime' => 60,
      'cache_expire' => 60, 
      'remember_me_seconds' => 60,
      'use_cookies' => true, 
      'cookie_httponly' => true,
),
```

in my module

```
 $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Configuration'); 
 $sessionConfig = new Session Config(); 
 $sessionConfig->setOptions($con fig['session']); 
 $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig); 
 $sessionManager->destroy(); 
 Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

Comment: Do you have the space between the `$con fig` in the original source also? Mayby that is the problem...

Comment: no I have coded $config,

Comment: Well, i suggest to update your question then with the right code and with new lines ( so we can read it better / understand it simpler )

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Zend, but here are my 10 bucks:

I think that you should set the variabel first before you destroy it.

So this piece of code:

```
 $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig); 
 $sessionManager->destroy(); 
 Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

Will then be:

```
$sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig); 
Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
$sessionManager->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e)

    $config = $e->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager();
        ->get('Configuration');

    $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
    $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
    $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig, null, null);
    Session::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
}
```

module.config.php

```
return array(
     'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
);
```

For cookie:

```
$expires = time()+60*60*24*30; // 1 month
$path = '/';
$usrCookie = new SetCookie('cpkue', $cookieUsrName, $expires, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting cookie_secure to FALSE and maybe increasing the time from 60 seconds

```
'session' =>  array
(
  'cookie_lifetime'      => 60 * 60 * 24 , 
  'gc_maxlifetime'       => 60 * 60 * 24,
  'cache_expire'         => 60 * 60 * 24, 
  'remember_me_seconds'  => 60 * 60 * 24,
  'use_cookies'          => TRUE, 
  'cookie_secure'        => FALSE,
),
```